# detecting if 2 keys down at same time

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple question 
just not sure what is wrong

I need to check if 2 keys are pressed at same time
the problem im having is
if i click the F key then let go then click the SHIFT key my code continues in the if

but im trying to make it that both have to be down at same time an just run once while there down till there released.

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) && GetAsyncKeyState(0x46/*F*/) &1)
```

Comment: It's probably better to use DirectX that plain old Windows API for something like this.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState returns *two* bits of information.  Compare the return value with < 0 to test if the key is down.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal:  [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called.  Calling it twice in a sequence cannot give you ganrantee that the two keys were pressed simultaneously.

You can consider [`GetKeyboardState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the status at one specific moment of all the virtual keys.

Comment: i tried it like this didnt even work with 1 key

    BYTE IsKeyDown[256];
    GetKeyboardState(IsKeyDown);

    if (IsKeyDown[VK_LSHIFT])
    {

Comment: Two remarks: the key is down if the high-order bit is 1 (the low order bit indicates toggling state);  and `GetKeyboardState()`, as `GetKeyState()` requires keyboard messages from the event queue to be processed whereas GetAsyncKeyState() is independent of the queue.  Do you process the keyboard messages in queue ?